# For what $x$ is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{y}}{y^x}dy$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{y}}{y^x}dy$

For what $x$ is the upper integral convergent?

My try:

$$|\frac{1}{y}| \leq |e^y y^{-x}|$$

Because $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}dy$$ is divergent, this implies that also $\int_0^{\infty}|e^yy^{-x}|dy$ is also divergent, so without the absolute values it is also divergent for every $x$ for which the upper inequality holds. I think it holds for all $x$.

Is the upper correct?

Comment: Why do you need absolute values when everybody is positive? Also, your inequality may not be true for all $y>0$. The basic idea is that the exponential function grows much faster than any power function.

Comment: Are we alowing complex $x$?  Then the integral could be oscillatory, thus have a chance to converge conditionally.  I still conjecture it diverges, though.

Comment: @Gary I see, it is only from $1$ to infinity.

Comment: @GEdgar It is only real analysis, but if  you think I would be able to understand it in the complex plane, then please continue.

Comment: If $y=2$ and $x$ is large and positive, the inequality will not be true.

Comment: @Gary how would you show that the integral is divergent

Comment: The interesting case is when $x>0$. Use, for $y>0$, $$
e^y  = 1 + y +  \cdots  + \frac{{y^{\left\lceil x \right\rceil  + 1} }}{{(\left\lceil x \right\rceil  + 1)!}} +  \cdots  \ge \frac{{y^{\left\lceil x \right\rceil  + 1} }}{{(\left\lceil x \right\rceil  + 1)!}},
$$ where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer which is greater than $x$. This implies $$
\frac{{e^y }}{{y^x }} \ge \frac{1}{{(\left\lceil x \right\rceil  + 1)!}}y.
$$